# 'IndexError: string index out of range' when index is shorter than the max index in the string. Python

Tags: python

So, first of all some context. As a small fun project I'm working on a small compiler that reads text files and is kind of like a fake programming language. Anyways, the same bug has popped up twice. Once for my 'if' statement and once for my 'math' statement in the language (it's read in python3 by the way). The bug is IndexError: String Index out of range even though the index is less that len(string)-1. Here is my code for the if statement:

```
    elif (code[0] + code[1]) == 'if':
        # sta is the index
        sta = 7
        i = 0
        varname = ''
        while i == 0:
            if code[sta] == '=':
                i = 0
            else:
                varname = varname + code[sta]
                sta += 1
        sign = code[sta]
        sta += 2
        i = 0
        condition = ''
        while i == 0:
            if code[sta] == ':':
                i = 0
            else:
                condition = condition + code[sta]
                sta += 1
        sta += 2
        if ints[varname] == int(condition):
            codeif = code[sta:(len(code) - 1)]
            readCode(codeif)
```

And the line that is causing the error is:

```
if code[sta] == '=':
```

The code I'm passing through is exactly *15* indexs long
Anyway I could use some help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What leads you to believe that `sta` is less than 14 when the exception is thrown?

Comment: have you tried stepping through your function in debug?

Comment: You can print the value of `sta` right before the problem line to see what values it has

Comment: I have stepped through the code in debug over and over. If I did not why would I post this?

Comment: As it would seem i already have. It just increments up. Maybe it's not finding the '='?

Comment: Can you show an example value of `code` that triggers the error?

Comment: Also, how exactly are you expecting the `while i == 0:` loop to exit? It's not at all clear what the intended purpose of any of these variables are, and it also comes across like you're trying to write the algorithm at a much lower level than is natural for Python. Have you heard of "tokenization"? Did you know there are guides out there to doing it with regexes? (Actually, how much formal compiler theory have you studied, or are you trying to figure it all out yourself?)

Comment: Sure thing! Here it is: ```if x= 9: chr *Hello!;``` Just for clarification. I have tried moving the equal symbol around to no avail.

Comment: And if you `print(code)` *immediately* above the `if code[sta] == '=':` line, you still see `if x= 9: chr *Hello!;`? And `print(sta)` shows `7`? (Wait, where did that value of `7` come from, anyway?)

Comment: It was just a fun project (as i said). And if you would have taken the time to read it you would know that. I am just trying to do something for fun not trying to dive into the deep pit of Lexers and Parse Trees.

Comment: The value of 7 is after I define the data I am working with as an integer in the ```code```

Comment: I did take the time to read. It being a "fun project" tells me *absolutely nothing* about your prior level of study.

Comment: I did not try to study it much. Just tried to do what I could with my prior knowledge in python.

Comment: If `code="if x= 9: chr *Hello!;"` and `sta=7`, then it is expected that your comparison will throw an IndexError. This happens because you increment `sta` on each iteration of the loop until it tries to access `code[21]` which is out of bounds.

Comment: You should put your sample input directly in the question at the top. You should also show some debugging statements that show that what you claim is true about the value of your counter, and when it throws the exception. Also also, half your comments shouldn't be belittling people who are trying to help you, esp. given your under-specified question. Please be a kind and grateful S.O. citizen!

Comment: As it would seem I am not trying to belittle people I am trying to show that I am not an expert on Lexers and that I do not intend to go into that field. I am telling them to expect the experience of someone who is working with making programming languages for the first time.

Comment: It would also seem "the other guy" is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `=` is at index 4, assuming your input of:

```
      012345678901234567890
code="if x= 9: chr *Hello!;"
```

But if `sta` starts at 7, and only increments, it will never find the `=`. Eventually `sta` reaches 21, which is > the max index of 20. So your claim that `even though the index is less that len(string)-1.` appears to not hold here.

As other commenters pointed out, there does not appear to be a way to exit that loop, as `i` starts at 0, is never modified other than to be set again to 0, and the loop only exits if `i != 0`. Just work on the logic a bit and you should be off and running again.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you Sam! You have made my day! Happy Coding to you aswell!